# Constraining parameters using mldivide

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix equation of the form `AX = B`. `A` and `B` are of size 1000x3 that I know. I want to cacluate `X`, which is a 3x3 matrix. However, some terms of this matrix are zeros and ones. i.e. `X` is of the form `[a 0 b; 0 c d; 0 0 1]`;

When I calcualte `X = A\B`, I get good approximations for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, but the values that I expect to be zeros are really small numbers.

Is there a way to constrain some of the parameters to be zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider solving each row independently. You technically have 3 systems of equations of the form `A*x_i=b_i`, for `A` [1000x3], `x_i` [3x1], `b_i` [1000x1].

Now, you can make `x_i` any shape, particularly, you can just remove the zeros (together with the vectors in A that multiply them).  If you know `x_3` is `[k 0 m]` (random example), that is the same as solving for `x_3` if size [2x1] ( `[k m]`)  and `A` of size [1000x2].

Don't waste computation multiplying by zero